# How do I setup Windsor container on a console application to inject to external library

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I have a console app and web API both referencing the same data layer which is a separate project.

In that data layer, I have a class that requires a repository that we are grabbing from the container when that class is instantiated.

In that class, it has a base class which we are doing the following in the constructor to setup the Repository:

```
IContainerAccessor containerAccessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
Repository = containerAccessor.Container.Resolve<IRepository>();
```

What would be the best way to set this up?  This is obviously a problem for our console application as it has no HttpContext.

Comment: One of several reasons service locator is considered an anti-pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: Why don't you inject the `IRepository` through the constructor instead of using a service locator (the `IContainerAccessor`)?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct you want to setup your console app so it can inject classes from the shared data layer.

To do so, you need to create an installer for the console app and tell it to run the installers in the shared library, but to modify the life style from 'PerWebRequest' to 'Singleton' or 'Transient'.

For more information read this article:
http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/ChangingWindsorlifestylesafterthefact/

Be aware that changing this may cause problems.
I.e.: If multiple components configured as "perWebRequest" require a 'Unit-Of-Work' to be injected, then this uow will be different for all components if you change the life style to transient.
Changing it to Singleton causes the same but opposite problem. Objects that are created now will have the same object for different requests ...

If you are okay with the problems this code should get you starting

```
public class ConsoleAppInstaller: IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        // 1) make sure we do not use PerWebRequest life style types
        var convertWebToTransient = new WebToTransientConvertor();
        container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(convertWebToTransient);

        // 2) call installers on all libraries we use ...
        container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<SharedDataLayerInstaller>());


        // 3) link internal services ...
        container.Register(Component.For<IXxxxFactory>().AsFactory());
        container.Register(Component.For<IYyyyFactory>().AsFactory());
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(c => typeof(Form).IsAssignableFrom(c)).LifestyleTransient());
    }

    public static IWindsorContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        return new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class allows to intercept installers using PerWebRequest lifestyles and replaces them with Transient life styles.
/// <code>container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new WebToTransientConvertor())</code>
/// </summary>
public class WebToTransientConvertor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    //http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/ChangingWindsorlifestylesafterthefact/
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.PerWebRequest)
            //model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;
            model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Singleton;
    }
}
```